# W3 validator errors help. Errors that do not seem to be wrong to me

Tags: html

first time here and hopefully I can get some help before the end of the day but. I ran my webpage and everything seemed to be fine and I was asked to put different portions into different elements. However, when I ran it in the validator it gave me several errors:

Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open.
Stray end tag head.
Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
  <head>
    <h1> JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>&nbsp;<br>
  </nav>
  <ul>
        <li>Specifalty cofee and Tea</li>
        <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
        <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
        <li>Open Mic Night</li>
    </ul>



  <div>12312 Main Street<br>
  Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
  1-888-555-5555</div><br>

  <footer><small><i>Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
  <a href="mailto:robert@scott.com">robert@scott.com</a></i></small></footer>



  </body>
</html>
```

If you can help or explain, it would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your TITLE needs to be in the HEAD section.  With it outside like that you are inferring a second HEAD section which is unacceptable.

Also the H1 should be removed from the HEAD section and placed in the BODY section.

I think you may have confused the HEAD section of the document with the HEADER tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  <h1> JavaJam Coffee House</h1>

  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>&nbsp;
    <br>
  </nav>
  </header>

  <ul>
    <li>Specifalty cofee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>

  <div>12312 Main Street
    <br>Mountain Home, CA 93923
    <br>1-888-555-5555
  </div>
  <br>

  <footer><small><i>Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
  <a href="mailto:robert@scott.com">robert@scott.com</a></i></small>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just beat me to it, this exactly.

Answer (score 1):

With corrections to the structure of the document, and added `<header>`, which I think is what you were getting at with `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
     <h1> JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
     <nav>
       <a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
       <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
       <a href="music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
       <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>&nbsp;
       <br>
     </nav>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>Specifalty cofee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>

  <div>12312 Main Street
    <br>Mountain Home, CA 93923
    <br>1-888-555-5555
  </div>
  <br>

  <footer><small><i>Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
  <a href="mailto:robert@scott.com">robert@scott.com</a></i></small>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

#### <header>

> The HTML `<header>` Element represents a group of introductory or
>   navigational aids. It may contain some heading elements but also other
>   elements like a logo, wrapped section's header, a search form, and so
>   on.

For a basic explanation of HTML document structure see this website:

- [W3Schools.com: HTML Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

For a more detailed and technical explanation, see this page:

- [W3C - The global structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html)